# Amazon Advertising API is not working with custom VPC endpoint policy for S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-vpc, amazon-product-api

Amazon Advertising API is not working with custom VPC endpoint policy for S3.

I have two S3 buckets and two EC2 instances in two VPCs. Created VPC endpoints to access S3 bucket.

I need to connect bucket `test1` from `EC2-1` in `VPC1` and bucket `test2` from `EC2-2` in `VPC2`. Need to block access from `EC2-1` to bucket `test2` and `EC2-2` to bucket `test1`.

These 2 buckets are under an AWS account and using same IAM user credentials to access these buckets.

Policy which I used for VPC Endpoint for S3 in `VPC1`:

```
{
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "Access-to-specific-bucket-only",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": [
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:ListBucket",
                "s3:PutObject"
            ],
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::test1",
                "arn:aws:s3:::test1/*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

This policy is working fine. But, I need to access Amazon Advertising API from my EC2 instances. Now, which gives a connection error. It will work when I give Full Access, that I do not want. Please help me to set up a custom policy.

**Note:** Amazon Advertising API URL start with https://amazon-advertising-api-reports-prod-usamazon.s3.amazonaws.com

Answer (score 1):

That looks like a URL where you can **retrieve reports** rather than an actual URL to the Advertising API.

Your VPC Endpoint for S3 policy is permitting access to the `test1` bucket, but it is not granting access to the `amazon-advertising-api-reports-prod-usamazon` bucket.

If you add that to your policy it be able to access the reports.